# Visual Studio can't run .lib file

Tags: c++, winapi

I downloaded an open source project from the internet written in c++,but when I try debugging it it shows up an error saying "Unable to start program....Is not a valid Win32 application".How can I run the .lib file?

Comment: A `.lib` file is a *static library*. It is something you use to link with an application, not something you run.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: A `.lib` file is primarily an *import library*, that can contain object code (which makes it a static library), but doesn't have to. Compile-time dynamic linking against DLLs is done through `.lib` files.

Comment: @IInspectable Not *primarily*. A `.lib` file is a static library, there's no going around that. It *might* be an import library, but it's just a special case of a static library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Static Library (.lib) files are not applications (.exe). If you want to use it, you will need to make an application and link the library to it.

If, by chance, this project comes with a testbed or demo project, you can switch it to be the "StartUp Project" by right-clicking on the project and selecting "Set as StartUp Project"