# How can I compile a .dll file from 2005 with MSVC?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, dll, compilation, msbuild

I need to compile an old version of the lame_enc.dll (MP3 encoder, version 3.97).

Unidirectional Migration to Visual Studio 2019 reported that changed to the code might be needed to create the project properly. When trying to compile the DLL, there were several warnings and the following errors.

```
C1189   #error:  Macro definition of snprintf conflicts with Standard Library function declaration  libmp3lame  C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\stdio.h    1935

LNK1181 Cannot open Input file "C:\Users\*\Desktop\lame-3.97\libmp3lame\Debug\libmp3lame.lib".  LameMp3EncDll   C:\Users\*\OneDrive\Desktop\lame-3.97\Dll\LINK  1
```

MSBuild and Devenv from 2019, 2015 and 2010 all resulted in the same error.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\stdio.h(1935,1): fatal error C1189: #error:  Macro definition of snprintf conflicts with Standard Library function declaration [C:\Users\*\Desktop\lame-3.97\libmp3lame\libmp3lame_vc7.vcxproj]
```

[This](https://sourceforge.net/projects/lame/files/lame/3.97/) is the exact version and files I'm working with.

What do I need to use/do to compile the dll?

Comment: Hi. Unfortunately, "It doesn't work" doesn't give anybody enough information to answer this question. You'll need to provide us with error messages and code snippets around the problem areas.

Comment: @Spencer I was hoping that there would be an answer not including the mentioned versions of Visual Studio. I included the information to prevent them from being answers. However, I will try to reproduce the errors and add them to my question. Thank you!

Comment: The problem could be that this dll has defined something with the name `snprintf` that in 2005 was not a problem but is now defined in the standard library. So you will have to modify the code of the dll to adapt it, eliminating that function, macro or whatever, and replacing it with the call to `snprintf` from the standard library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What do I need to use/do to compile the dll?

Visual Studio 14+ defines `snprintf`to `_snprintf` in `stdio.h`.

**Solution**

**1)** run VS2019 as Administrator and then reopen your project

**2)** please change these  in `stdio.h` file:

```
 #if defined snprintf
 .....
 #endif
```

**to**

```
#if _MSC_VER < 1900
#  define snprintf _snprintf
#endif
```

**3）** `Edit`-->`Find and Replace`-->`Find in Files`-->

**Find what**: `#\s*define\s+snprintf`

**Look in**: Entire Solution ( Including External Items )

choose `Match case` and `Use Regular Expressions`

[image]

So please change `#define snprintf _snprintf` to:

```
#if _MSC_VER < 1900
#  define snprintf _snprintf
#endif
```

**Note**： change these in `id3tag.c` file

change

```
#ifdef _MSC_VER
#define snprintf _snprintf
#endif
```

to:

```
#if _MSC_VER < 1900
#  define snprintf _snprintf
#endif
```

**Update 1**

The `libmp3lame` project is a class library project and we cannot debug lib project directly, the way is that we should run a executable project(xxx.exe) and then reference this lib, after that, we can debug it. See [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42051840/visual-studio-cant-run-lib-file).

[image]

I found that the `lame` project is a executable project which I think it already referenced `libmp3lame.lib`, so you should change it as startup project first and then right-click on the project-->properties-->Linker-->General-->change Output File to `$(OutDir)$(TargetName)$(TargetExt)`.

**Or** create a new executable project and then references `libmp3lame.lib`. How to reference lib you can refer to [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/9de9cc87-4275-4285-9b96-aea109768a67/lib-is-not-a-valid-win32-application-visual-studio-2017?forum=vcgeneral).

Comment: In stdio.h, there is no line `#define snprintf _snprintf`, only `#define snprintf Do not define snprintf as a macro` (line 1931). Should I replace this with your given code instead?

Comment: Sorry for the late answer, I was busy and not able to follow your instructions until now. Following your instructions, I was able to compile the lame_enc.dll by opening BladeMP3EncDLL.c and compiling the file. However, using the included configurations of the project lead to another error: `Unable to start program 'C:\Users\*\Desktop\lame-3.97\libmp3lame\Release\libmp3lame.lib'. C:\Users\*\Desktop\lame-3.97\libmp3lame\Release\libmp3lame.lib is not a valid Win32-Application`. Should I add this to my original question, or is it enough to have it in the comments?

Comment: The issue is that you can not run and debug a library project, the `libmp3lame` is actually a library project. When you want to debug a library project, you should run a executable project(.exe) and then reference this `libmp3lame` in it to debug it and since you can compile the project successfully which is the original question, so I  suggest you could accept it. Besides, since you want to debug this project, you should set lame as startup project and then right-click on the project-->properties-->Linker-->General-->change Output File to `$(OutDir)$(TargetName)$(TargetExt)`.

Comment: I accepted the answer, debugging the whole project was not my intention. Thanks for your help!