# Program can't find twitcurl.lib and I don't know how to specify the location

Tags: c++

I am very new to twitcurl API and therefore i follow the steps of this one person in [YouTube](https://youtu.be/eITwklZMckc) when I try to implement Twitcurl API. I did all the steps and reach the final point and try to debug my program which it then shows that the program cannot start [directory to the file] and that the system cannot find the file specific. The warning is fairly straight forward and try to add the directory (Librarian, Linker, etc..) in the properties setting and I still couldn't make it work.

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2fw3j.png)
[directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1jQJ5.png)

Comment: You sure that the path specified is correct? The `\.\\` looks very suspicious

Comment: make sure you put the file (or a symlink) in one of your compiler's library path

Comment: How do i do the symlink?

Comment: ln -s <SOURCE> <LINK_NAME>

Comment: can you post the output of ```cd \; DIR twitcurl.lib /s``` so we can see where you've placed the library?

Comment: output file (Librarian): C:\Users\Joey Tan\Desktop\twitcurl-master\twitterClient\lib\twitcurl.lib

Comment: @WrathOfTux Directory of C: \Users\Joey Tan\Desktop\twitcurl-master\twitterClient\;ib

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to get it worked. The problem is that since it is a library and that library is static and should not be able to run independently. The solution is quite simple, just run the main application separately and not run the library. [One user in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42051840/visual-studio-cant-run-lib-file) mentioned that library are static and this helps a lot.